# why is the same code structure working in some places, but not others for coloring cells

Tags: excel, for-loop, colors, range, background-color

I'm trying to make a Userform to select different worksheets, and select the columns and the starting row to compare the cells to find matches.
the color coding is failing for one worksheet, but not the other. depending on methods to reference the Range, will yield different errors for the second work sheet... (its always the second worksheet that errors, and I don't understand why?)

I use a double For Loop to scan the cells and inside the For loops, have a couple If Then Else statements to do the comparing work. Once it compares, sets the cells to either red or green... (also used a couple different methods of coloring too) would like to eventually add color to the Userform so the operator can select what ever color they want...

This is the original method I started with.

```
Application.Worksheets(LIST_A).Activate
Worksheets(LIST_A).Range(tC1C1 & x).Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
   '.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    .ColorIndex = 4
    .TintAndShade = 0.25
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
'   Stop
End With
```

very slow, and as I was building more color changing on both worksheets instead of just one, it started to fail on the B sheet.. (I keep the code as List_A and List_B)

The second attempt,

```
Set WKS_A = WKB.Sheets(LIST_A)
'(did this for both A and B)
With WKS_A
      WKS_A.Range(tC1C1 & x).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
      WKS_A.Range(tC1C1 & x).Cells.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.25
End With
```

this has worked wonderful for A but fails on B everytime....

```
With WKS_B
    WKS_B.Range(tC2C1 & y).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    WKS_B.Range(tC2C1 & y).Cells.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.25
End With
```

(error is Run-time error 1004, Application-defined or Object-defined error), if I hover over the .colorindex line, it gives a value of -4142, like it's reading the colorindex instead of replacing it with 4...?

the only change is the B in the WKS_B. and the tC2C1 & y, each corresponds to the different sheets in the For Loop structures.
I've tried to Set the range:

```
Set r2 = WKS_B.Range(tC2C1 & y)
r2.Interior.ColorIndex = vbGreen
```

> (run-time error '9' Subscript out of range)

now that I've worked through a couple methods, I don't understand why always it fails on B... I don't understand what I've done wrong or really where to look?
I've verified that I'm re-using variables anywhere in the application..
and of course, I've tried rebooting (hahaha...)

Comment: What is the value of `tC2C1 & y`?

Comment: If `WKS_B` is accepted as a valid assignment for a worksheet object (meaning, Excel can find the worksheet and it's not mis-typed), then your next source of error would be `tC2C1 & y`. What is that value and is that valid? Try to assign it to an intermediate variable, e.g. `Dim colorRange As String; colorRange = tC2C1 & y; WKS_B.Range(colorRange)...`. Basically, you have to check all the pieces to find out which one is causing the error, as @BigBen is suggesting.

Comment: tC2C1 & y are strings, tC2C1 = Column2Column1... = the column from worksheet 2 and y is the row (variable of the For loop)  so the value of (tC2C1 & y) equals e247 as the cell address of the range. (maybe a bit odd to use range for 1 cell, but I've tried WKS_B.Range(tC2C1 & y & ":" & tC2C1 & y).cells..... also, same failure).....

Comment: got it figured out.... always the second sheet was my hang up.... oh yea, my other code protects that sheet when it reports the data from sql, kinda my way of protecting data from idiots... like me.....